# Why could a text be written in one line in a div?

Tags: html, css

I am using a template to build a website. The problem is that in a slider I am writing a text inside a div created by me, and the text is shown in one line, so it overflows the div. I cannot understand why the text is not shown in the right way. I tried to search for the problem looking for the CSS classes which are affecting the parents' tags, but I do not see anything wrong.

```
<div class="caption text sfb" data-x="1" data-y="266" data-speed="400" data-start="1200" data-easing="easeOutExpo">
  <div style="max-width: 40% !important; overflow: auto;">
    Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
  </div>
</div>
```

The text *Blah blah blah...* is shown in one line, and it ignores *max-width: 40%*. If I write the property overflow, the text respects the *max-width*, but is still in one line, which I do not want.

My question is: anyone knows any CSS property which I can use with an *!important* to fix this behaviour?

Comment: It’s probably the `white-space` property that’s responsible.

Comment: Try : <div style="max-width: 40% !important; white-space:normal!important; overflow: auto;">

Comment: I guess there's something wrong in the code we can't see, cause when you put code you provided in fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fqvb11sx/ it's not shown in onw row, it is broken in 2 quite logically..

Comment: Btw your question seems very unclear to me, the header looks like you maybe want it to be in one line but under the code you write that you don't want it in one line so I'm confused.

Comment: @Ms. Nobody: I think I did not write very well the title because of my poor english.

Comment: @Akwebmedia: Thank you! That code works perfectly! Write it as an answer if you want.

Comment: @forvas looks like you got the answer anyway :P

Comment: @forvas Please vote for my answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<div style="max-width: 40% !important; white-space:normal!important; overflow: auto;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to change your `max-width:40%` which only take the width of 40% from your parent `div` try changing `max-width:100%`

**OR**

If you want your content to scroll try this

```
div{
    word-wrap:normal;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a4u2qcws/1/)**

Comment: Thank you for your help! With this code I cannot manage which I want, because I do not want scrollbars, the right code is the one @Akwebmedia wrote.